# Can't find the option to change privacy policy for Android app already on play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have privacy policy of my app set to the wrong link which isn't working (it has unnecessary .html extension which breaks the link). However, as weird as it sounds, I cannot seem to find the place in play console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) or elsewhere to change that link. When I go to store listing I see some details I can change including the name, short/long description, screenshots, email, website...but no privacy policy. I googled without success finding the answer to something that seems should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your app in console, then move to Store presence > App Content. There you will get the privacy policy option. Click on manage to edit privacy policy URL. Refer below image.

[image: Privacy Policy]

Answer (score 0):

the new face of the playstore ...  near to settings ,   I found it on ...

[image]